# Passing data to my app upon install

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Is there a way to pass data to my app upon install from a link to the appstore. Perhaps through a query string or something of that nature.

I am looking for some way to allow the user to purchase a license and pass that license to the app install as easily as possible.

Any information and limitation information as well would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of information?  Just do a registration in your app like what a social networking app does.  I just download that new "HBO GO" and I add the create a "HBO GO ID."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store will not pass any query strings after the installation. There are really not much analytics other than how many people bought your app, and currently no real way to figure out where they came from.

As for the reasoning behind it too, another limitation may be App Store rules in general. It sounds like your licensing issue may be better solved through In App Purchases.

Comment: well I am not actually selling anything as Im just giving the license for nothing. what I am trying to do is to get the application to know who they are but not require them to sign in. I guess that was a bit of a stretch. You have probably pointed out the only real approach.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of in your case would be possibly registering a URL scheme, then have the user click a link on the website on their iPhone that redirects to the application, but at that point may be more complex than just logging in.

Comment: My colleague and I came to the same conclusion. I think the best path is the login.